# How do I switch spaces without using `keystroke` with Apple Script?

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-catalina

I'd like to run an apple script that follows these steps-

1. Make a web browser full screen
2. Open another application which disables my keyboard
3. Return to the web browser

When I make the web browser full screen it moves to the space one to the right of the current space.

If I write something like `tell applications Web Browser to activate` then it will go to an active window, but not necessarily the one that is full screen. If there's any other window open, then it'll go to that window.

This is my script so far

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "n" using {command down}
    end tell
end tell
    
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}
    end tell
end tell

tell application "KeyboardCleanTool"
    activate
end tell
```

I'd now like to return to the Firefox window.

Comment: Basically, you cannot Applescript Spaces at all. If you don't use fullscreen, then you can easily key command Spaces, but not fullscreen Spaces.

Comment: Can I go full screen without using keyboard shortcuts?